# is it possible to get the PowerBI report Screenshot or reports inside Microsoft-Teams using bot framework v4?

Tags: node.js, botframework, powerbi, microsoft-teams, powerbi-embedded

Using Bot framework V4 is it possible to get a screenshot of powerbi report inside the Microsoft Teams using Azure Blob storage otr just by passing the link of an pbix dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In teams, you can press the + :
[image]

To add a TAB, here you have the option to include a power bi report:

[image]

Comment: is it possible for bots also?

Comment: That depends what you want to do with the bot, what is your workflow? Please update your question so we understand what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to programmatically export a Power BI dashboard / graph to an image. If you want to show a Power BI dashboard / graph in Teams via a bot, I would make use of the possibilities to use a tab.

- [Combine your bot with a tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-with-tabs) and [create a deep link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links) to your tab from the bot. The custom tab included with your bot will receive the context and you can build a web application that loads the right dashboard using Power BI embedded.

Comment: @Sai - There are different ways, One is create a web app and pull it inside teams as a tab. The other way is to use the PowerBI tool which is provided inside Teams and it will help you pull the reports/dashboards inside teams. 
The second question was about bot - There are different ways you can achieve it, one is [Deeplink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deep-links) to tab other way is to show report in [Task Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-bots) from a Bot.